# Automatically encode request body object into JSON

Tags: java, groovy, jackson, feign

I'm using OpenFeign/feign to send API requests:

```
import feign.Body
import feign.Param
import feign.RequestLine

interface ApiServiceInterface {
    @RequestLine("POST /container/{cid}/key/bulk")
    @Body("{bulk}")
    public void bulk(@Param("cid") Long cid, @Param("bulk") Bulk bulk)
}
```

**`@Body("{bulk}")` is not working**, because it converts the object  into a string:

```
[ApiServiceInterface#bulk] ---> POST http://localhost:5050/container/11/key/bulk HTTP/1.1
[ApiServiceInterface#bulk] Content-Length: 45
[ApiServiceInterface#bulk] 
[ApiServiceInterface#bulk] com.***.tns.hoth.key.bulk.Bulk@5dd5fb75
[ApiServiceInterface#bulk] ---> END HTTP (45-byte body)
```

**Is there any way to *automatically* convert objects into JSON objects?**

This is how I build the `Feign.Builder`:

```
    def mapper = new ObjectMapper()
    mapper.setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))
    mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
    mapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.SNAKE_CASE)
    mapper.readerForUpdating(this)

    return Feign.builder()
            .logger(new Logger.JavaLogger().appendToFile("logs/hoth.log"))
            .logLevel(Logger.Level.BASIC)
            .decoder(new JacksonDecoder(mapper))
            .encoder(new JacksonEncoder(mapper))
```

Comment: `@Produces` annotation in JAX-RS exists for a reason

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of OpenFeign when we use

```
@Body("{bulk}")
public void bulk(@Param("cid") Long cid, @Param("bulk") Bulk bulk)
```

`Bulk` object `toString()` is used to map the parameter value. If you want to convert the `Bulk` object to necessary json string, just do the following

```
public void bulk(@Param("cid") Long cid, @RequestBody Bulk bulk)
```

You don't have to put `@Body` annotation.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

You can try

```
def feignJson = JsonSlurper.toJson(feignObject)
```

and then, optionally

```
def pretyJsonOutput = JsonOutput.prettyPrint(feignJson)
```

check details:
http://groovy-lang.org/json.html